# Sort by emails in Gmail by subject line

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to sort the email I get in Gmail by the subject?

I don't mind if I have to use a Greasemonkey script, but I haven't found anything relevant.

I don't want to use third-party email applications to do this. I want to be able to sort my email using the Gmail web interface.

Comment: The best bet is to use Thunderbird with gmail's imap settings

Comment: @Benny: I'd agree, but that doesn't meet with the "no third-party apps" criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, even with greasemonkey, as some of the messages/conversations you want to sort might not be on the page at the time — they could be pushed back to pages 2,3,4,etc, and thus invisible to greasemonkey.

But this is google, and google is, after all, founded on search.  If you click the little `Show search options` link just to the right of the search box, you'll get a page that allows you to search based on subject only (as well as many other fields).  This is likely a lot more efficient than sorting anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information. in general you are right. filtering is must more efficient then just searching by subject.

Comment: Search isn't always a substitute for listing. One requires recall, the other only requires recognition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Filter option to automatically apply filters to e-mails as they come in. You can filter them by subject (ie: A webletter e-mail prefixes itself with the company's name thus you can filter e-mails out using that particular search string.)

You can also what Joel suggested and use the Seach Bar at the top.